# Get-ADComputer to return a different property than queried?

Tags: powershell, select, active-directory

I am using Get-ADComputer to search through my domain for a specific string in the Location property. However, when I find it, I want to return the Name property the string was found in.

My company is using Powershell version 5.1 if that makes a difference.

I've already tried piping Name after "select-string -Pattern 'example'" but it simply returns nothing, I assume it thinks I'm looking for the property within Location rather than the Get-ADComputer result. The answer will probably be someone telling me to store the whole Get-ADComputer as a variable, but I'm not sure what the data limit on Powershell variables are, and it seems I would be parsing through quite a lot of data.

```
Get-ADComputer -properties Location -SearchBase "OU=E, DC=M" -filter 'Name -like "*"' | select Location | select-string -pattern "example"
```

My current result is the entire Location property, but my desired result is the Name property while searching for the location. It would be even better if I could return both.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are looking for the string `example` within location, you can filter on location and then output the name.

```
Get-ADComputer -SearchBase "OU=E, DC=M" -Filter "location -like '*example*'" | Select-Object Name
```

If you are looking for the string `example` within Name, you can filter on Name and still output the name.

```
Get-ADComputer -SearchBase "OU=E, DC=M" -Filter "Name -like '*example*'" | Select-Object Name
```

If you want to output more properties including location and Name, you will need to add the `-properties` switch to handle location.

```
Get-ADComputer -Properties location -SearchBase "OU=E, DC=M" -Filter "Name -like '*example*'" | Select-Object Name,location
```

If you are looking to find string `example` within any property that outputs by default from the `Get-ADComputer` command, then you will need something like the following:

```
Get-ADComputer -Properties location -SearchBase "OU=E, DC=M" -Filter * | Where-Object { $_ | Out-String | Select-String -pattern "example"}
```

Explanation:

`Select-Object` will output a custom object with the properties that you have selected. The `-Filter` on the AD commands has limited operators available. If you are looking for a simple string, know what property contains the string, but don't know where the string exists within the string, use the `-like` operator. The `*` characters are for wildcards. `-Filter` is almost always faster than piping into something else, so you should use it if you can.

The `Where-Object { $_ }` processes the current object (`$_`) in the pipeline, which includes all of the properties piped into the command. If you only want to compare a single property, then `$_` should become `$_.propertyname`.

Comment: Wow, thank you for simplifying my craziness. I've been staring at the screen for the last eight hours and seem to have wanted to make my life 103924901x more complicated. You're the 'bomb'